# what to do after adding a package to already deployed meteor app?

Tags: meteor

I added some packages like account-ui with meteor to an already deployed meteor app...however the changes are not appearing?

Comment: Have you redeployed the app?

Comment: do you mean run the deploy command again? yes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop your application,
Then run

> Meteor add **some_package**

and run

> Meteor

again to start your application 
The packages should be deployed automatically.

Comment: what about if I want to deploy to somedomain.meteor.com? running `meteor` seems to start a local instance.